# SQL injection Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to prevent the sql injection in oracle:

```
begin
                my_pkg.verify_user(pview => :pview,
                  pusername => 'sample@email.tst'||dbms_pipe.receive_message(chr(98)||chr(98)||chr(98),9)||'',
                  ppassword => 'ygsMq/NCuntF7us35f8UaQ==');
    end;
```

If this is passed in the test case the return is generated after 9 seconds.
How can I prevent this type of injection?

```
PROCEDURE verify_user(pview     OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                    pusername user.email%type,
                    ppassword user.password%type) IS
```

This is the procedure I'm using.

Comment: If you defined the `verify_user` procedure, you'd need to update the procedure to avoid SQL injection.  Presumably, the procedure is using dynamic SQL for some reason and not validating the input parameters.  It isn't obvious to me why you'd need to use dynamic SQL to verify a user or why, if you do so, the username would not be a bind variable in whatever SQL you do need to generate dynamically.  But since you haven't included the implementation, we can only guess.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a complete [MRE] including: the value returned by `DBMS_PIPE.RECEIVE_MESSAGE` (does it return a value or does it time out?); the **FULL** code for your procedure so we can see where the "SQL injection" is happening; what the output from the procedure is; what the expected output from the procedure is.

Comment: This code is helpful for attacking websites
I think this code will not be accepted by stackoverflow
My website is attacked by same injection followed by

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using bind variables in your procedure and are not using dynamic SQL (you do not give the code for the procedure so we cannot verify this assumption).

The SQL injection is happening in your test setup and not in your procedure and the delay is **NOT** in your procedure, it is in your test setup. You should find that if you run:

```sql
DECLARE
  p_username VARCHAR2(100);
  p_password VARCHAR2(100);
  p_time1    TIMESTAMP;
  p_time2    TIMESTAMP;
  p_time3    TIMESTAMP;
  p_time4    TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  p_time1 := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  p_username := 'sample@email.tst'||dbms_pipe.receive_message(chr(98)||chr(98)||chr(98),9)||'';
  p_time2 := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  p_password := 'ygsMq/NCuntF7us35f8UaQ==';
  p_time3 := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  my_pkg.verify_user(
    pview => :pview,
    pusername => p_username,
    ppassword => p_password
  );
  p_time4 := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Username creation time: ' || (p_time2 - p_time1) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Password creation time: ' || (p_time3 - p_time2) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Procedure run time: ' || (p_time4 - p_time3) );
END;
/
```

You should find that the username creation time is 9 seconds (as it waits to create the pipe and then for it to time out) and the execution time of your procedure is negligible.

Sanitise your inputs and don't dynamically run SQL without at the very least passing user entered inputs as bind variables. Also, make sure you blame the correct issue; in this case it is likely to be in your test setup and not the procedure.

Comment: `begin
     my_pkg.verify_user(pview => :pview,
        pusername => 'b11.com'||dbms_pipe.receive_message(chr(98)||chr(98)||chr(98),9)||'',
        ppassword => 'lFLyMtjr+W0Go9TDceth+g==');
    end;`

I'am intercepting my login and then my log is generating this which is giving me delay.

Comment: I got your point but the issue is when PHP is calling the oracle procedure the variable has dbms pipe in it

Comment: @Taimoor Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66900444/edit) your question with the full details of the question; if you are calling it in PHP then add the PHP code to the question as well as adding the PL/SQL code for the procedure. If there is behaviour that is happening in another session that is influencing the outcome then describe that behaviour and give us a way of replicating it. Help us to help you by editing **YOUR** question to give us a complete [MRE]. We can't give you a good answer if you only describe half the problem.